# Model modification in NgOnInit is not reflected in the html view

Tags: angular

I'm loading data from firestore, triggering this within NgOnInit method once I got the route params. The changes are not being recognised in the html view/template.

My code is :

```
public board:BoardModel;

...

constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute, 
  
  private boardService: BoardService) { 
    this.board = new BoardModel();
    this.board.name = "hello";

  }

async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
  this.actionidSubscription = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(async (params) => {
     this.boardid = params['boardid'] || "";

     console.log("board/view => boardid received", this.boardid);

     
     this.board = await this.boardService.getBoard(this.boardid);
    

     console.log("View => ngOnInit => this.board", this.board);
 });

}
```

My template :

```
{{board.name}}
```

The output that I'm getting is

> hello

which is the value that I had set in the constructor to test this.

How do I ensure that the updated model in ngOnInit is available in the template, or reflected once the data is ready ?

The console is showing the retrieved model (`console.log("View => ngOnInit => this.board", this.board);`).

Comment: Can you see `this.board` being updated in the subscription ?

Comment: in the console I can see this board being populated when console.log("View => ngOnInit => this.board", this.board); is being executed.

Comment: Well your code looks fine. Could you please provide us a Stackblitz that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've sorted it out. I've manually triggered change detection and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by triggering change detection manually.

1. inject ChangeDetectorRef

   constructor(private changeDetectorRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}
2. When you update the model call detectChanges()

   this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();